# How to get name of a required page in flask?

Tags: python, web, flask

I know that in the following way one can bind in flask a required page with a certain function:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/hello.py")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

@app.route("/goodbye.py")
def defgoodbye():
    return "Goodbye Wordl!"

@app.route("/")
def defgoodbye():
    return "Root!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

However, I need more flexibility. I know that thousands of different pages can be requested and I would like to know which one was requested (hello.py or goodbye.py or hello_1232.py or something else). Can I do it just with one function?

Comment: Did you read the quickstart yet? The [routing section](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart/#routing) shows you how to create variable rules.

Comment: Are you sure you want to add the `.py` extension to the url? Maybe `/file/<filename>` would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for a catch-all url: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/57/

The route below will match any path that starts with hello and ends with .py. I agree with @msvalkon though that you probably don't want or need your routes to end with .py

```
@app.route("/hello<path:path>.py")
def hello(path):
    return "Hello World!"
```